# Pipeline parallel job ansicolor output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, ansi-colors

I have a Jenkinsfile with parallel builders. Is it possible to make executors of parallel build more distinguishable by colorizing the name of each executor?

The following is a simplified example of what I have tried so far, withouth being able to see any colors in the build console output:

```
def builders = [:]
builders["\u001B[31m RED BUILDER \u2717 \u001B[0m"] = {
}

node("nodename") {
    wrap([$class: 'AnsiColorBuildWrapper']) {
        parallel builders
   }
}
```